# Furthest Distance Between Two Points on a Rectangular Prism

Tags: geometry, inequality, optimization

If the path between two points $x,y$ on a rectangular prism is the distance one would have to travel on the prism to reach point $y$ from $x$, what is the largest possible distance between two points on a prism?

I think I may have the solution, but it's very ugly, with lots of algebra, and I'm not sure if it's correct, or if I'm overlooking something. Suppose the prism has dimensions $a<b<c$. I think logically, one would place the two points(call it $x,y$) on opposite corners of the prism.

[image: My Diagram so far]

Now, we want to go in straight lines, so we have to figure out which face to traverse first, and then, which point to aim for(we will call it $s$), and then we're done. Since $c$ is the longest length, I figured we would split this up, and so the path that seemed reasonable to me is the following:

[image: The path is in red]

To figure out what $s$ is, I note that the length of the path is $$\sqrt{a^2 + s^2} + \sqrt{(c-s)^2 + b^2} $$ and taking the derivative, and finding the critical point, we get that this is minimum when $s = \frac{ac}{a+b}$.

Is this correct? Does my reasoning make sense, or did I overlook something? I'm actually not sure how to rigorously prove that this path is indeed the minimum(besides a lot of inequality bashing potentially) and I can't justify for sure if these are where the points should be placed, to be honest. Is it just a lot of algebra to prove this?

Thank you!

Comment: To find the $s$ or the crossing point from one face to another, you may also unfold those two faces to form a bigger rectangle, and consider the diagonal.

Comment: My apologies, @Goku241.  I misunderstood your question, so I deleted my answer.

Comment: "I think logically, one would place the two points(call it ,) on opposite corners of the prism." This is not true in general. See for example: http://www.se16.info/js/cuboid.htm#Ant